# Joint probability mass function of $\max(X,Y)$ and $\min(X,Y)-\max(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are independent geometric variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with geometric probability function $p(k) = (1-\pi)\pi^{k}$ for $k = 0,1,...$ and $0 < \pi < 1$. Let $U = \max(X,Y)$ and $V = \min (X,Y)$. Define $W = V  - U$.

I want to find the joint probability mass function of $U$ and $W$.

My attempt:

I found the distribution of $U$ by cumulative function of geometric distribution and independness:

$$
P(X \leq k) =  1 - (1 - \pi)^{k} 
$$

$$P(U \leq u) = P (X \leq u, Y \leq v) = P(X\leq u) P(Y\leq u) $$

How do I find the distribution of $W$ or any attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: The title is misleading. You want the joint probability mass function of two variables that are neither independent, nor geometric.

Comment: You may find [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578951/find-the-probability-function-of-x-1x-2-in-geometric-distribution) [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040620/the-distribution-of-the-minimum-of-two-independent-geometric-random-variables) [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259247/geometric-probability-mass-function) questions helpful.

Comment: And also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685256/a-question-regarding-independence-of-min-x-y-and-x-y-when-x-y-follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=1,2,\ldots$
$$
\mathbb P(W=-k)=\mathbb P(\max(X,Y)-\min(X,Y)=k)=\mathbb P(X<Y, Y=X+k)+\mathbb P(Y<X, X=Y+k) = 2\mathbb P(X<Y, Y=X+k)=2\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=i, Y=i+k) = \ldots
$$
You need to calculate it.

For $k=0$
$$
\mathbb P(W=0)=\mathbb P(\max(X,Y)=\min(X,Y))=\mathbb P(X=Y) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=i, Y=i) = \ldots
$$

And the distribution of $W$ is found.

All the rest is to find 
$$
\mathbb P(W=-k, U=m)=\mathbb P(\max(X,Y)=\min(X,Y)+k=m).
$$
For $k=1,2,\ldots$, $m\geq k$
$$
\mathbb P(W=-k, U=m)=\mathbb P(\max(X,Y)=m, \min(X,Y)=m-k) = 2\mathbb P(Y=m, X= m-k).
$$
For $k=0$, $m\geq 0$
$$
\mathbb P(W=0, U=m)=\mathbb P(Y=m, X= m).
$$
After all you need in $\mathbb P(U=m)$, find it from cdf of $U$ which you already found.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I appreciate.

Comment: You are welcome! 
After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you сould "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).